# Change state from reducer not from root state using React-Redux when data is inherited

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Good afternoon. I am writing an application using react-redux and faced a dilemma. I have already re-thought it several times and can't choose how to organize the project and data structure correctly and conveniently. Design data by inheriting or composing data. I initially went along the path of composition, but I realized that it is inconvenient when there is a one-to-one relationship. I decided to change it to inheritance, because it seemed logical from the point of view of data organization, but there was a big difficulty with `reducers`, more precisely, I am confused that it turns out to be a single root `reducer` with a lot of `actionTypes`keys . I remember about performance, when elements inherit a data chain from a common ancestor, that this is very bad. And yet I chose this path and I have a question: Please tell me if it is possible to split into several `reducers` for each level of nesting data. Example

```
onst initState: IPages = {
  idActive: 0,
  pages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: `Tab #1`,
      workspace: {
        idActiveDraggableElements: [],
        idActiveLines: [],
        attributes: {
          height: string,
          width: string,
          viewBox: [0, 0, 5000, 5000]
        },
        draggableElements: [], // more data
        lines: [],  // more data
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Reducer:

```
export function pagesReducer(
  state: IPages = initState,
  action: IPageActionTypes
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_PAGE":
      let uniqId = getUniqKeyIdOfArrayList(state.pages);
      return {
      ...state,
      pages: state.pages.concat({id:uniqId, title:`Вкладка - ${uniqId}`})
    }
    case "REMOVE_PAGE": return {
      ...state,
      pages: state.pages.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
    }
    case "CHOSE_PAGE": return {
      ...state,
      idActive: action.id
    }
    case "RENAME_PAGE":
      let indexPage = state.pages.findIndex(item => item.id === action.id);
      state.pages[indexPage].title = action.title;
      return {
      ...state
      }

      // ===================
      // LONG LIST WHAT BAD...
      // It's a bad idea to add editing to the `workspace` field and then `draggableElements`. `lines` 
      // ... but I understand that this will happen, because I don't know if there is another way.
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Can I edit the `workspace' node without updating the entire application state?

Thanks you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data modeling aspect for a 1-to-1 relationship, you can choose either to reference by id or to embed the data. It depends on your query pattern.

In your case which is embedding, you can make use of [memoized selectors](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data).

Ideally, since you have an `idActive`, update your `pages` data structure to be an object instead of a list.

Like so:

```
{
  pages: {
    '1': {
       workspace: { ... },  
    }
  }
}
```

Then for your reducer, think of it as slicing a tree (or nested attribute). Your reducer would then look something like:

```
function workspaceReducer(state, action) {
  // TODO
}

function pagesReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_WORKSPACE': {
      const { id } = action;
      const page = Object.assign({}, state.pages[id]);
      return {
        ...state,
        pages: {
          ...state.pages,
          [id]: {
             ...page,
             workspace: workspaceReducer(page.workspace, action)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then to prevent unnecessary re-renders, using memoized selectors,
it would be like:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const pages = state => state.pages;
const activePage = state => state.idActive;

const getActivePage = createSelector(
  activePage,
  pages,
  (id, pages) => pages[id]
);

const getWorkspace = createSelector(
  getActivePage,
  page => page.workspace
);
```